# checkbox can't be set initial value in xaml?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

In xaml put code as:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="cbxNew" Content="New" IsChecked="true"  Checked="cbxNew_Checked"  />

private void cbxNew_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.txtTest.Text = "";
        }
```

then run the app and got error:

```
Set Property
System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.IsChecked threw an exception
```

very surprised. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please provide some surrounding XAML code; the above line should by itself not cause any problems. Also, provide more exception details.

Comment: Thanks. Updated with the full xaml and code for Checked event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs because the Checked event is firing during the dialog/page's InitializeComponent() but before txtTest has been assigned a value.

Simply change the code to

```
private void cbxNew_Checked( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
  if ( this.txtTest != null )
    this.txtTest.Text = "";
}
```